# Best practice provision form library with custom template

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I exported a site collection template that I wanted to apply a brand new site collection. The problems start with the form libraries:

```
    <pnp:ListInstance Title="Form-Index" Description="Form-Index" DocumentTemplate="{site}/FormIndex/Forms/template.xsn" TemplateType="115" Url="FormIndex" EnableVersioning="true" MinorVersionLimit="0" MaxVersionLimit="6" DraftVersionVisibility="0" TemplateFeatureID="00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115" EnableAttachments="false" DefaultDisplayFormUrl="{site}/FormIndex/Forms/DispForm.aspx" DefaultEditFormUrl="{site}/FormIndex/Forms/EditForm.aspx" DefaultNewFormUrl="{site}/FormIndex/Forms/Upload.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/itfl.png?rev=44" IsApplicationList="false" ValidationFormula="" ValidationMessage="">
      <pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
        <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x010101" Default="true" />
        <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x0120" />
      </pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
    </pnp:ListInstance>
```

The proces stops here with this:

> Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Invalid template URL. The template
>   must exist in the Forms directory of this document library. Create the
>   template in the Forms directory, and then re-type the Web  address.
>   Note that you cannot move or copy a template into the Forms directory.

This is strange, because the template indeed says: 
 
`DocumentTemplate="{site}/FormIndex/Forms/template.xsn"`

The form library has a template created with InfoPath. The problem might be that the template itself is not downloaded, at least I don't see neither any trace in the template xml nor a file created in the target folder. I used the following command to create the pnp template:

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out "C:\Users\me\Documents\PnPtemplate\clone.xml" -Schema LATEST -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles -Handlers All -IncludeNativePublishingFiles
```

I searched for the issue, but all I found was a bug on github related to content types and I don't use a custom content type.

So, the question is, how can I create the form library with PnP? Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
DocumentTemplate="{site}/FormIndex/Forms/template.xsn"
```

with

```
DocumentTemplate=""
```

in xml file and retry

Comment: This worked for my while importing a site template in SPO. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanTahir I'm glad to help!)